# Set value to a column on the row where its ID exists in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I want to create a View where it has all the columns from Table1 and receives an additional column called "Photo_Exist" appended to it and it is assigned "1" or "True" if ID in Table1 exists in Table2.

**Table1**:
ID, Col1, Col2, ..., Coln

**Table2**:
Linked_ID

**View**:
ID, Col1, Col2, ..., Coln, Photo_Exist

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T2.Linked_ID=T1.ID) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
       END AS Photo_Exist
FROM Table1 AS T1
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a view using this query. This should help

```
  select table1.*, case when table2.linked_id is null then 0 else 1 end as Photo_exist 
    from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.id =table2.linked_id
```

Comment: +1 But you need to remember that if there are more than one `Linked_ID` in `Table2` corresponding to `ID` in `Table1` than you'll get several rows in result set with the same `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

I like using sub-queries for this type of thing.

```
select
    t1.*,
    Photo_Exists =
        case
            when t2.Linked_ID is null then 0
            else 1
        end
from Table1 t1
    left join
    (
        select distinct 
            Linked_ID
        from Table2
    ) t2 on t1.ID = t2.Linked_ID
```